# Как задать внешние условия для выполнения hook-а?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как можно задавать внешние условия для выполнения хука на wordpress?

К примеру, я хочу, чтобы хук сработал, только если тип продукта не `variable`

```
public function woocommerce_add_hooks() {
global $product;
if($product->product_type != 'variable') {
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 
'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 1);
}
}
```

вот так - получаю ошибку.

Comment: Что написано в ошибке?

Comment: @Streletz да ничего - пустая страница с html и body

Comment: в `wp-config.php` прописать `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` тогда будет понятнее про ошибку